# How to read random data sent from android to Mac OSx?

Tags: android, macos, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, data-transfer

I developed an android app that sends data (text, binary, hex..etc) using bluetooth communication. I want to test my app, what methods are there?
Is there a method on mac to receive what is sent ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an app called LightBlue on the Mac (and iOS) App Stores which is very useful when developing with BLE. It allows you to scan, see advertisement data (iOS version only), connect, list services and characteristics, subscribe to a notify / indicate characteristic and read or write a characteristic's value.

For classic Bluetooth, if using SPP you will need a serial terminal. First you need to connect to your device from the Bluetooth System Preferences. This will create a device file in `/dev`, its name follows the pattern `/dev/cu.<DEVICE_NAME>-SPPDev` where `DEVICE_NAME` is the advertised Local Name. This is a character device that you can use with any program that can `read(2)` and `write(2)` to a file. For instance the simplest way with default tools, if your device file is `/dev/cu.XXXX`, is to run `cat /dev/cu.XXXX` in one terminal window (or `cat /dev/cu.XXXX | hexdump -C` for hex output), then in another terminal window run `echo -n "my command" > /dev/cu.XXXX`. Then in the first terminal window you will see the response from your device. For hex input you can use the `-e` switch and backslash escapes, for instance to send 0x01 0x02, you would run `echo -ne "\x01\x02" > /dev/cu.XXXX`.

There are programs that are specialized in this sort of communication, called serial terminals. These also let you change the serial port configuration, although the one selected by osx is generally good. I personally use [cutecom](https://github.com/M1cha/Cutecom) for this. In cutecom, you need to input the device file name (`/dev/cu.XXXX`) in the "Device" text field, then configure the desired serial port parameters. To use those that osx selected, just uncheck the "Apply settings when opening" checkbox. Then click on "Open device". You can then input text or hex and see output as text or hex also. If you get gibberish on the output that means that the serial port parameters are not good. If you don't know the right parameters for your device you can experiment, but a typical configuration would be Baud rate : 115200; Data bits : 8; Stop bits : 1; Parity : None, and no handshake.

Comment: Thank you. I have used this app to discover the services and characteristics but this app shows only this. It doesn't show me what my developed android is sending....its only for BLE i guess also

Comment: Yes it's only for BLE. It was not clear from your question that you were also interested in classic Bluetooth. For SPP I personally use cutecom : https://github.com/M1cha/Cutecom

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I have looked at it but I don't understand how I can use it...is there an easy guide for it or something...Im a new developer